# ncurses nodelay for responsive arrow key feedback

Tags: ncurses

I am trying to write integers to a file using ncurses and the keyboard arrows. I use nodelay so that I can write a 4 to the file while nothing is being pressed.  ESC exits the program. The problem is that all I can ever write to the files is 4. ESC seems to work fine, so the switch is working. If I take out the nodelay the program works but 4 cannot ever be writen.

Thanks

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ofstream outFile;
   char outputFilename[80];
   sprintf(outputFilename, "files/file.%s",argv[1]);
   outFile.open(outputFilename, ios::out);
   int ch;
   initscr();
   nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);
   raw();
   keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
   noecho();
   refresh();
   while(1){
      ch = getch();
         switch(ch)
         {
            case KEY_UP:
               outFile << 0 << endl;
               break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
               outFile << 1 << endl;
               break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
               outFile << 2 << endl;
               break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
               outFile << 3 << endl;
               break;
            case ERR:
               outFile << 4 << endl;
               break;
            case 27:
               outFile.close();
               endwin();
               return 0;
               break;
            default:
               break;
         }
      refresh();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by checking to see if the last value of ch was ERR before writing 4 to the file.  Not sure I understand completely... maybe a timing issue.  New program:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   ofstream outFile;
   char outputFilename[80];
   sprintf(outputFilename, "interactive/taker.%s",argv[1]);
   outFile.open(outputFilename, ios::out);
   int ch;
   int ch_prev=0;   
   initscr();
   nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);
   raw();
   keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
   noecho();
   while(1){
      ch = getch();
         switch(ch)
         {
            case KEY_UP:
               outFile << 0 << endl;
               break;
            case KEY_DOWN:
               outFile << 1 << endl;
               break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
               outFile << 2 << endl;
               break;
            case KEY_LEFT:
               outFile << 3 << endl;
               break;
            case ERR:
               if (ch_prev != ERR)
                 outFile << 4 << endl;
               break;
            case 27:
               outFile.close();
               endwin();
               return 0;
               break;
            default:
               break;
         }
      ch_prev=ch;
      refresh();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the check, you will overlook the lines which are not 4's, since almost all of the return values are ERR's.  Also - the program will be using a lot of CPU (doing nothing).  You would get better results if you used [timeout](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html) with a fairly short value (10-50 milliseconds) rather than nodelay.